# In typescript, use the `void`, but have to specify the value

Tags: typescript, void

```
type Item<D> = {
  type: string;
  data: D;
};

const hello: Item<number> = {
  type: 'hello',
  data: 12345,
};

// Property 'data' is missing in type '{ type: string; }' but required in type 'Item<void>'
const world: Item<void> = {
  type: 'hello',
};
```

If I define type as `void`, I thought that I don't have to specify a value. but it's not.

Why?

Do I have to create and use a type like below to solve this problem?

```
type OmitVoidValue<T> = {
  [V in keyof T as T[V] extends void ? never : V]: T[V];
}

const hello: OmitVoidValue<Item<number>> = {
  type: 'hello',
  data: 12345,
};

const world: OmitVoidValue<Item<void>> = {
  type: 'hello',
};
```

Comment: `data` is not an optional property - it *has* to be there. You've declared that its value doesn't matter but its existence does not depend on the value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will need to make a mapper type alias to remove the `data` from the required type when It is instantiated with `void`

You are using `key remapping` for all of the keys, instead of that you can just omit the `data` field.

Your approach might fail in case you have a function type that returns a void
`foo: () => void`

```
type Item<D> = {
  type: string;
  data: D
}

type GetItemType<T> = T extends void ? Omit<Item<T>, 'data'>: Item<T>

const hello: GetItemType<number> = {
  type: 'hello',
  data: 12345,
};

const world: GetItemType<void> = {
  type: 'hello',  
};
```

[Code Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsA8ARAfFAvFA3gWACgopRIAuKAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBuQ4gEwENguKVCAX0KFS0AOIRgcRABVwEJLIzZZUCAA94DDpSgA3APZ0OUAPxQA8gjrAkM5MoA0UAOTdertBQdK0IggBjQwZqKAALCAAbKMMKSWl4BHlIJAYAVwQAIwgaFVx2EgUKV0iYw1cnQo8%20KABGACYAZgAWAFYqgkE2AkJg0OAoAHdDGiiOeKkHFMUjE3z8IiLyNzLYyuIhFiA)